# Is it correct to use the present simple tense to describe the past?

Tags: tense

I hired a freelancer who is a native English speaker to improve my writing. The text is about why some ex-prisoners commit crime again after their release. That is to say, what happened before they went to jail is in the past. But he used the present simple tense to describe the past (the bold part). Is this correct? If it's correct, is it better than using the past simple?

> **Many people commit crime in the first place because of poverty. They
> have no skills to find a job that offers livable wages, so they commit
> theft to support themselves.** After separation from society with years
> in prison, and with a criminal record, they become even more
> undesirable in the job market. This leaves them little choice but to
> continue to make a living by illegal means after their release.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Among other things, the simple present can be used to express general realities, things that are generally this way. For example

> Dogs bark.

can mean that some dogs are barking right now. It can also mean that barking is something that dogs do in general. Simple present is used in this manner in the quote in your question.

Additionally, there's the so called [historical present](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Historical_present), also called "narrative present" or "dramatic present". This isn't used in your example, but it's another form where present tense grammar is used to describe events from the past.

Answer (score 1):

That paragraph is **not** about the past, because it is **not** about the specific actions of the ex-prisoners in question.  It is a general statement about why people commit crime. As a "general fact" it is in the simple present.

The paragraph "sets the scene".  Later the author might talk about the specific actions of the ex-prisoners, and for that, the tense will shift to a past tense.

> Many people commit crime in the first place because of poverty... Joe committed crime because he was addicted to gambling. When he was fired from his job, he began to steal from houses. He lost most of the money he stole gambling on horses.